# ActionController::UnknownFormat: New User Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Please could i get some assistance as you all are very helpful!

I am trying to load the index page on a new users sign up. It should load with only requests created by them but as they have not created any yet im getting the error below.

ActionController::UnknownFormat in RequestsController#index
Started GET "/requests.15" for ::1 at 2019-05-14 13:06:11 +0100
Processing by RequestsController#index as
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:20:in `index'

Here is my requests index controller

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    if current_user.landlord?
      @requests = Request.where(house: current_user.houses).order("created_at DESC")
      respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.pdf do
            pdf = RequestPdf.new(@request)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "request_report.pdf",
                                  type: "application/pdf",
                                  disposition: "inline"
          end
        end
    elsif current_user.tenant?
      @requests = Request.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @requests = Request.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
      respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.pdf do
            pdf = RequestPdf.new(@request)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: "request_report.pdf",
                                  type: "application/pdf",
                                  disposition: "inline"
          end
        end
    end
  end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have an issue with your URL.  `/requests.15` is the wrong format. it must be `/requests/15` or `/requests15` or `/requests`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by remove '(resource)' from my after_sign_in_path_for within application_controller.